# Bash script to take backslash and dash as an argument

Tags: bash

I am currently writing a script that allows the final user to give a number (from 0 to 100) has an argument, this should not allow any letter or special characters. So far, I haven not been able for it to reject any `\`  or `-`.

Here is one of many things that i have tried:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 =~ ['°¬~`^<>@!#$%&/()=?¡¨*:;_,.-{}+´¿a-zA-Z'] ]] || [[ $1 =~ '\' ]]; then

        echo "Invalid input"
        sleep 1
        read -p " Press [Enter] to continue"
        clear

else

        echo "Valid input"
        sleep 1
        read -p " Press [Enter] to continue"
        clear
fi
```

I know that it can be done with just read -r (at least the backslash) but since it is used to keep a transactional service alive, every second is very important, that is why i need to do it with just a one liner "./script.sh 123" rather than adding the input validation after executing the script.

This is just a simple script to test the conditional, in the production script it does not wait for the user to press Enter, it just show the modification on an XML file and then exits.

I have tried doing `\\.` `'\\'`, `'\'`, just the `\`  inside then brackets like the other characters. `"\\"`, `"\"`.

With the dash, I can just valide that the number is not lower than zero, but if the user input is 12-3, it allows this value to the XML.

Comment: The `sleep` and `read` and `clear` shoud be outside the conditional, or, frankly, removed entirely.

Comment: Yes, i know that those are unnecesary,this is just to make it easier for other users (since it needs to get approved for other people in order to implement it on the production service). Even though, I get what you are saying, i could just typed it once outside the conditional and do the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hugely overcomplicating things.

```sh
case ${1#-} in
 *[!0-9]*) echo "$0: invalid input" >&2;;
  *) echo "$0: valid input" >&2;;
esac
```

If you specifically want to match backslash or dash, the glob `[-\\]` does that.

The parameter expansion `${1#-}` allows an optional minus sign; if you don't want that, just use plain `$1`.

Comment: I have tried your solution, it checks if a dash is given but not the backslash. I tested your suggestion of using `[-\\]` but it does not work (may be because i am still learning Bash i am putting this in the wrong place):

[root@VTOOLSPR01 bin]# ./regexp.sh 20\
> ^C
[root@SERVER ]# ./regexp.sh 2-0
./regexp.sh: invalid input
[root@SERVER ]# ./regexp.sh \
> ^C
[root@SERVER ]# ./regexp.sh 20-
./regexp.sh: invalid input

I putted that like this:

case ${1#-\\} in
*[!0-9]*) echo "$0: invalid input" >&2;;
  *) echo "$0: valid input" >&2;;
esac

Comment: On the command line, `20\ ` does not produce a literal backslash. Try `20\\ ` or `'20\'` to pass a literal backslash through to your script.

Comment: Now it says that is an invalid input like intended, but if the user puts a backslash alone the prompt stays at >; is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Not really; you are escaping the newline. If your users are unfamiliar with the shell, perhaps have them provide their input through other means.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I am gonna check for other ways to pass the numbers.